# ASP.NET MVC 1.0 and Castle ActiveRecord 2.0 Lazy Loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lazy-loading, castle-activerecord

How do I access a lazy loaded property of an ActiveRecord model from within the view?

I have a news model that Belongs to a Category Model, both of which are marked as Lazy=true

I'm able to access a lazy loaded property in my view by doing the following in my controller

```
using (new SessionScope())
{
    results = _service.FindAllNews(start, pageSize, new[] { Order.Asc("Id") });
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        var category = result.Category;
    }
}
return View(results);
```

Then in my view, I parse through the results and display the category title with the following

```
<%= Html.Encode(item.Category.Title) %>
```

Obviously if I don't reference the property in my controller, I will get a session scope error when trying to call the property in the view.

But this seems wrong to me.  Is there a better way of initializing the lazy loaded properties of a model before reaching the view?  I suppose I could write an Init function in the model, but that also seems wonky as well.

Comment: I've ran into the same thing with regular NHibernate.  I had to end up moving my transaction to the BeginRequest and EndRequest.

Comment: Your comment should be a answer, mxmissile. Having a single SessionScope per request would solve his problem, although you have to be careful if using auto flushs.

Comment: Yea, but I'm not familiar with AR's SessionScope or AR for that matter, not sure if it's transaciton usage is the same as regular NHibernate, in other words didn't feel qualified.. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the responses, but AR doesn't manage session scopes in the same way that nHibernate does.   In AR, you don't have to manage session scopes at all unless you are using lazy loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I turned to the AR google group and found the answer I was looking for. I thought I would share it with everyone here in case someone else is looking for the same thing.

To change where the session scopes are created and destroyed for lazy loading with ActiveRecord, you should add the following to your web.config.

```
<system.web>
    <httpModules>
        <add 
            name="ar.sessionscope" 
            type="Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.SessionScopeWebModule, Castle.ActiveRecord" />
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

This changes where the session scope is created and disposed to match the session scope per request here http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/usersguide/web.html.

Answer (score 3):

The simple solution is: Don't perform Lazy loading within your view.
The View in MVC by definition has no business loading anything.

It's up to the controller to do that so you can test this behavior.

And yes, you don't need to set that in your mappings. You can query your objects with another Fetchmode so they get eagerly loaded in that one particular case.

Comment: While the marked answer is directly what the user was asking, this is a better answer.  The View shouldn't do anything that touches the DB.